# How can I convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, utf-8, utf-16

As far as I know, Excel use UTF-16 to represent string literals. I read from a console (Mac) / file (Windows), and in both cases the character encoding is messed up. I have to find a solution which works on both platforms, so ADO stream is not an option. I made some debugging and I see that actual bytes are:

```
Bytes     | Displayed as | Should be | Correct byte
258,129   | Ă           | Á         | 193
258,356   | ĂŤ           | Í         | 205
313,176   | Ĺ°           | Ű         | 219
313,144   | Ĺ           | Ő         | 213
258,347   | Ăś           | Ü         | 220
258,8211  | Ă–           | Ö         | 214
258,353   | Ăš           | Ú         | 218
258,8220  | Ă“           | Ó         | 211
258,8240  | Ă‰           | É         | 201
```

(Comes from the good-old hungarian test-phrase, ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP which contains all of our special characters).
I am looking for an algorithm which results in the correct string both on Mac and Windows.
Thanks!

Comment: Mojibake: file is UTF-8, interpreted in `cp1250` (Central Europe). Proof in Python: `'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1250','replace')` yields `'Ă�RVĂŤZTĹ°RĹ� TĂśKĂ–RFĂšRĂ“GĂ‰P'`. Reverse way is impossible, IMHO. Open file using proper encoding.

Comment: On Windows I could use ADODB.Stream which works well. On Mac I use popen/fread from libc.dylib which returns the string like this. Any idea how to read UTF-8 from the console?

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers posted so far will correctly transcode an input string containing codepoints from the full Unicode range like for example "‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍UnicodeSupportest‍‍‍‍‍♀️‍♂️‍❤️‍‍♀️".

That's why I wrote the following function, using only VBA inbuilt functions/statements that are available on both, Windows and MacOS.

This function works cross-platform and cross-app, and for the entire Unicode range.
`codePoints > 65535` are also supported, even though VBAs inbuilt `ChrW()` and `AscW` don't support them, because the transcoding is done entirely "manually", including surrogate pairs. Performance should also be relatively good since the function works on a single byte-array buffer. If someone finds a bug or improvement, please let me know!

This code was improved as a result of [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284102/234277) on CodeReview, many thanks to [Cristian Buse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8488913) for that!

```vb
'Function transcoding an UTF-8 encoded string to the VBA-native UTF-16-LE
'Author: Guido Witt-Dörring, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457
'                            https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools
Public Function DecodeUTF8(ByRef utf8Str As String, _
                  Optional ByVal raiseErrors As Boolean = False) As String

    Const methodName As String = "DecodeUTF8"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numBytesOfCodePoint As Byte

    Static numBytesOfCodePoints(0 To 255) As Byte
    Static mask(2 To 4) As Long
    Static minCp(2 To 4) As Long

    If numBytesOfCodePoints(0) = 0 Then
        For i = &H0& To &H7F&: numBytesOfCodePoints(i) = 1: Next i '0xxxxxxx
        '110xxxxx - C0 and C1 are invalid (overlong encoding)
        For i = &HC2& To &HDF&: numBytesOfCodePoints(i) = 2: Next i
        For i = &HE0& To &HEF&: numBytesOfCodePoints(i) = 3: Next i '1110xxxx
       '11110xxx - 11110100, 11110101+ (= &HF5+) outside of valid Unicode range
        For i = &HF0& To &HF4&: numBytesOfCodePoints(i) = 4: Next i
        For i = 2 To 4: mask(i) = (2 ^ (7 - i) - 1): Next i
        minCp(2) = &H80&: minCp(3) = &H800&: minCp(4) = &H10000
    End If

    Dim codepoint As Long
    Dim currByte As Byte
    Dim utf8() As Byte:  utf8 = utf8Str
    Dim utf16() As Byte: ReDim utf16(0 To (UBound(utf8) - LBound(utf8) + 1) * 2)
    Dim j As Long:       j = 0
    Dim k As Long

    i = LBound(utf8)
    Do While i <= UBound(utf8)
        codepoint = utf8(i)
        numBytesOfCodePoint = numBytesOfCodePoints(codepoint)

        If numBytesOfCodePoint = 0 Then
            If raiseErrors Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid byte"
            GoTo insertErrChar
        ElseIf numBytesOfCodePoint = 1 Then
            utf16(j) = codepoint
            j = j + 2
        ElseIf i + numBytesOfCodePoint - 1 > UBound(utf8) Then
            If raiseErrors Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, _
                    "Incomplete UTF-8 codepoint at end of string."
            GoTo insertErrChar
        Else
            codepoint = utf8(i) And mask(numBytesOfCodePoint)

            For k = 1 To numBytesOfCodePoint - 1
                currByte = utf8(i + k)

                If (currByte And &HC0&) = &H80& Then
                    codepoint = (codepoint * &H40&) + (currByte And &H3F)
                Else
                    If raiseErrors Then _
                        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid continuation byte"
                    GoTo insertErrChar
                End If
            Next k
            'Convert the Unicode codepoint to UTF-16LE bytes
            If codepoint < minCp(numBytesOfCodePoint) Then
                If raiseErrors Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Overlong encoding"
                GoTo insertErrChar
            ElseIf codepoint < &HD800& Then
                utf16(j) = codepoint And &HFF&
                utf16(j + 1) = codepoint \ &H100&
                j = j + 2
            ElseIf codepoint < &HE000& Then
                If raiseErrors Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, _
                "Invalid Unicode codepoint.(Range reserved for surrogate pairs)"
                GoTo insertErrChar
            ElseIf codepoint < &H10000 Then
                If codepoint = &HFEFF& Then GoTo nextCp '(BOM - will be ignored)
                utf16(j) = codepoint And &HFF&
                utf16(j + 1) = codepoint \ &H100&
                j = j + 2
            ElseIf codepoint < &H110000 Then 'Calculate surrogate pair
                Dim m As Long:           m = codepoint - &H10000
                Dim loSurrogate As Long: loSurrogate = &HDC00& Or (m And &H3FF)
                Dim hiSurrogate As Long: hiSurrogate = &HD800& Or (m \ &H400&)

                utf16(j) = hiSurrogate And &HFF&
                utf16(j + 1) = hiSurrogate \ &H100&
                utf16(j + 2) = loSurrogate And &HFF&
                utf16(j + 3) = loSurrogate \ &H100&
                j = j + 4
            Else
                If raiseErrors Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, _
                        "Codepoint outside of valid Unicode range"
insertErrChar:  utf16(j) = &HFD
                utf16(j + 1) = &HFF
                j = j + 2

                If numBytesOfCodePoint = 0 Then numBytesOfCodePoint = 1
            End If
        End If
nextCp: i = i + numBytesOfCodePoint 'Move to the next UTF-8 codepoint
    Loop
    DecodeUTF8 = MidB$(utf16, 1, j)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had to solve this, I came up with the following function which can successfully transform the characters which are between 128 and 255

```
Private Function utf8ToUTF16(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim i&, l1%, l2%, l3%
    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        l1 = Asc(Mid(strText, i, 1))
        If i <> Len(strText) Then l2 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 1, 1))
        Select Case l1
        Case 194
            utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l2): i = i + 1
        Case 195
            utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l2 + &H40): i = i + 1
        Case 197
            utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l2 + &HC0): i = i + 1
        Case 203
            utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l2 + &H240): i = i + 1
        Case 226
            If l2 = 128 Then
                l3 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))
                utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l3 + &H1F80)
                i = i + 2
            ElseIf l2 = 130 Then
                l3 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))
                utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l3 + &H2000)
                i = i + 2
            End If
        Case Else
            utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & Chr(l1)
        End Select
    Next i
End Function
```

Now passing "ĂRVĂŤZTĹ°RĹ TĂśKĂ–RFĂšRĂ“GĂ‰P" to this function (which is read from a standard UTF-8 encoded file) will return "ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP".

- Note: this is not be the most efficient code, for sure. Whenever I call it I always use it on the shortest string possible. Currently I use it to decode a result from cURL, and passing the whole HTML froze it.

EDIT

Now I had some time to clean up this.

```
Private Function utf8ToUTF16(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim i&, l1&, l2&, l3&, l4&, l&
    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        l1 = Asc(Mid(strText, i, 1))
        If i + 1 <= Len(strText) Then l2 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 1, 1))
        If i + 2 <= Len(strText) Then l3 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))
        If i + 3 <= Len(strText) Then l4 = Asc(Mid(strText, i + 3, 1))
        Select Case l1
        Case 1 To 127
            l = l1
        Case 194 To 223
            l = ((l1 And &H1F) * 2 ^ 6) Or (l2 And &H3F)
            i = i + 1
        Case 224 To 239
            l = ((l1 And &HF) * 2 ^ 12) Or ((l2 And &H3F) * 2 ^ 6) Or (l3 And &H3F)
            i = i + 2
        Case 240 To 255
            l = ((l1 And &H7) * 2 ^ 18) Or ((l2 And &H3F) * 2 ^ 12) Or ((l3 And &H3F) * 2 ^ 6) Or (l4 And &H3F)
            i = i + 4
        Case Else
            l = 63 ' question mark
        End Select
        utf8ToUTF16 = utf8ToUTF16 & IIf(l < 55296, WorksheetFunction.Unichar(l), "?")
    Next i
End Function
```

As I realized, characters above 55295 (D7FF) will not appear, so it will output a question mark instead as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple VBA code worked well for Spanish accented characters in a text file. Given a string with the UTF-8 double-characters it returns a string with accented characters:

```
Function UTF8to16(str As String) As String
Dim position As Long, strConvert As String, codeReplace As Integer, strOut As String

strOut = str
position = InStr(strOut, Chr(195))

If position > 0 Then
    Do Until position = 0
        strConvert = Mid(strOut, position, 2)
        codeReplace = Asc(Right(strConvert, 1))
        If codeReplace < 255 Then
            strOut = Replace(strOut, strConvert, Chr(codeReplace + 64))
        Else
            strOut = Replace(strOut, strConvert, Chr(34))
        End If
        position = InStr(strOut, Chr(195))
    Loop
End If

UTF8to16 = strOut

End Function
```

Comment: Can confirm that works for Lithuanian too.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
Function utf8ToUTF16(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim binText() As Byte, i As Long
    'size the binary buffer
    ReDim binText(Len(strText) - 1 + 3)
    'insert BOM in 0,1,2 positions
    binText(0) = &HEF
    binText(1) = &HBB
    binText(2) = &HBF
    'append text characters
    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        binText(i + 2) = Asc(Mid(strText, i, 1))
    Next
    'write to a binary stream
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .write binText
        'convert to the text stream
        .Flush
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2
        .Charset = "utf-8"
     'read the result skipping BOM
        .Position = 3
        utf8ToUTF16 = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I stated in the original post: "I have to find a solution which works on both platforms, so ADO stream is not an option.". It works on Windows indeed, but this is not available on Mac.