# Excel VBA (365) on Mac (Ventura): ensure UTF-8 csv-files are loaded using UTF-8

Tags: excel, vba, macos, csv, utf-8

Every month I need to load hundreds of UTF-8 formatted csv-files directly into an VBA array on mac (Ventura).

How can I specify "UTF-8" or "code page 65001" or "Unicode (UTF-8)" or similar when using the Open file statement?
I do not find it in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement#syntax

The following code results in garbled Japanese kanji:

```
Open filePath For Input As #1
    fileContent = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1
```

(English works fine)

I have confirmed that the csv-files are in fact UTF-8 formatted.

Based on what I found regarding mac's default encoding, it is supposed to be UTF-8, however, it seems that Excel on mac doesn't use this default (UTF-8). It does not matter whether I run mac in English or Japanese mode.

I have tried different Open statement options such as the following. But they do not compile:

```
Open filePath For Input Mode As #1 Len = 100000, Format := "Unicode (UTF-8)"
    data = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1
```

Further, the "`Scripting.FileSystemObject`" library is not available on mac so I can't use:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Nor can I use `CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")`

The only approach that works so far is to load the csv-file into a workbook. However, I need to load the csv-file directly into an array.

```
With sh.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & Filename, Destination:=sh.Range("A" & lLastDataRow))
            .TextFilePlatform = 65001
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .Refresh
            .Delete
        End With
```

Obviously, the key here is the "`.TextFilePlatform = 65001`" part. How do I specify this for the Open file statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Open` statement can not deal with the UTF-8 conversion.

Since we know that VBA and Excel use UTF-16LE internally, we can just read the binary contents of the file and do the UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion later. As you already noted, this is a bit tricky on Mac because of the lack of `ADODB.Stream` and `FileSystemObject`.

I wrote a function that manually transcodes UTF-8 to the VBA internal UTF-16 using only VBA inbuilt functions and statements that are available cross-platform. I have already posted it in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457) and will therefore just [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457) it here to avoid duplication and make maintenance easier.

Using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457), you can easily read and decode your files like this:

```vb
Sub ReadUTF8FileDemo()
    Dim fileNum As Long: fileNum = FreeFile
    Dim path As String:  path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\UTF-8_file.csv"
    
    Dim b() As Byte
    Open path For Binary Access Read As #fileNum
        ReDim b(0 To LOF(fileNum))
        Get fileNum, , b
    Close #fileNum: fileNum = 0
    
    Dim dataStr As String
    dataStr = DecodeUTF8(CStr(b))
    'DecodeUTF8 function available here:
    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457
    
    Debug.Print dataStr 'Voilà
End Sub
```